# Where application bundles get their environment variables from?

Tags: terminal, applications, python, environment-variables

A user of my (Python based) app reports that they can't open it in regular way (via double clicking the icon in Finder) -- nothing just happens. When they run it from Terminal, they get an error (from bundled Python 3, I presume) about unexpected value in an environment variable:

```
PYTHONPATH is currently: "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
     You should `unset PYTHONPATH` to fix this.
```

When they unset it and run my app (in Terminal) again, everything works fine.

I suspect that the same variable is to blame when they run the app from Finder. How to find out where this variable is being set? I know there is `.bash_profile`, but launching an app bundle isn't about Bash? Or is it?

Comment: The only python that's in /usr/local/lib would normally be something installed from python.org, not either of the system python installs.  Homebrew is broken, but that's not where it tries to put python.  macOS also does not set PYTHONPATH by default, so either your application bundle, or this python install in /usr/local/lib is doing it.

Comment: @MarcWilson, thanks! My app does not set it. Where can this other Python installation persist the variable?

Comment: I found some guidance from Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-on-os-x

Comment: If your bundled Python needs a particular environment, why is it not settig it up?  The correct answer is not figuring out why machine (A) sets this variable, it is dealing with the fact that the variable is set.  Why aren't you resetting it?  That wouldn't survive past your invocation anyway.

Comment: @MarcWilson, that's what I'm going to do -- shadowing selected `PYTHON*` variables in Info.plist. I just wanted to understand where they come from so that I can reproduce the problem in my computer.